# How to fix diamond subclassing in cocosdx

Tags: c++

I have a base class:

```
class MTBGameObject : public CCNodeRGBA
```

and I created two other classes:

```
class MTBGamePlayer : virtual public MTBGameObject, virtual public CCSprite
class MTBGameObstacle : virtual public MTBGameObject
```

But now I'm unable to use any property of MTBGamePlayer, and I can't cast it.

Comment: he is not using problem as it is a banned word in the title of questions!

Comment: @mc110 Really? What a great example of why blacklists are a bad solution to pretty much any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching to solution of this problem but couldn't find anything..
So I came up to this solution, I know it's not the best but unless it's working it fine.

```
class MTBGameObject {
    ...
    virtual CCNodeRGBA* self() = 0;
}
```

and then in child classes I have to override self function:

```
class MTBGamePlayer : public MTBGameObject, public CCNodeRGBA {
    ...
    CCNodeRGBA* MTBGameObstacle::self() {
        CCNodeRGBA* node = dynamic_cast<CCNodeRGBA*>(this);
        return node;
    }
}

class MTBGameObstacle : public CCSprite, public MTBGameObject {
    ...
    CCNodeRGBA* MTBGamePlayer::self() {
        CCNodeRGBA* node = dynamic_cast<CCNodeRGBA*>(this);
        return node;
    }   
}
```